# The view's window field is nil in viewDidAppear method?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, viewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

I have several `NSViewControllers` that reference a field of the view's `NSWindowController`. My understanding of the view's lifecycle contract would indicated that I can rely on on the view's window being populated by the time the `viewDidAppear` is called. And that has been the case until today's apparent Xcode update (when I started Xcode it seemed to update some libraries, now at version 9.0 (9A235)). Now, when `viewDidAppear` is called on my NSViewController instance, the `self.view.window` field is actually nil! Code looks like this (with some debugging stuff added):

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    if let w = self.view.window {
        if let bmw = w.windowController {
            rf = (bmw as! BudgetMunkyWindow).refreshManager;
            rf.add(listener:self);
        } else {
            print("There was not window controller");
        }
    } else {
        print("there is no window");
    }
    self.categoryTable.reloadData()
    categoryTable.expandItem(nil, expandChildren:true)
}
```

Did this contract change at some point in the recent past? At this point, I can't gain access to the window controller at any point during the construction of the view, which is awkward to say the least.

Comment: if let w = self.view.window {} doesn't sound because it has no reference to a window controller.

Comment: Just checked the docs for `NSViewController`, but can't find anything about querying the window... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller

Comment: `NSView` hoewever **does** have a `viewDidModeToWindow()` method. Not very practical to subclass `NSView` for all your view controllers, though... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483329-viewdidmovetowindow

Comment: Perhaps you can subclass just **one** of your view controller's view, override the property `window` with an observer, and try to see exactly **when** it is set to an actual value.

Comment: Can't override that property(it's read-only), that would have been a great way to find out when that field gets set! did override viewDidMoveToWindow(), that tells me that method is called **after** viewDidAppear().

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? I encountered the same issue and I can't understand how this is possible. The view's appeared but there's no window? (scratching my head)

Comment: My problem was that I was calling a performSegue in ViewDidLoad and the ViewDidAppear didn't have a valid `view.window` at that point. Seems very uniquely affecting my case though but something to consider.

Comment: Same here. Occasional crashes due to `window` being `nil`. Madness. I suppose the docs for `viewDidAppear` leave enough wiggle room for the window not necessarily having to be valid when the method is called.. but still: madness!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around from my App that include some debug code. It takes 1-2 iterations to break out of the loop after the func is called from viewDidAppear

```
var mainWindowTrialCount: Int = 0

func setWindowTitle() {
if let window = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow {
  mainWindowTrialCount = 0
  var titleString = toggleSimulationConfigurationButton.title + ", " + selectedComputeGPUButton.title
  if selectedComputeGPUButton.title != "Compute: CPU" {
    titleString.append(", " + asyncSyncComputeButton.title)
  }
  window.title = titleString
  print(titleString)
} else if mainWindowTrialCount < 10 {
  //work around for window not being valid at viewDidAppear
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
    self.mainWindowTrialCount += 1
    let elaspedTime: Float = Float(self.mainWindowTrialCount) * 0.01
    print("Initialization time = \(elaspedTime)")
    self.setWindowTitle()
  }
}
```

}